# apache is not allowing me to use port number 443 in virtual tag for configuring apache for https service

Tags: security-certificate, httpd.conf, xampp, openssl

I am trying to configure apache for https service in xampp , i am almost done i am jsut struggling with that virtual tag in which i have give information about my self-signed ssl-certificate and key file , apache is not allowing me to use port number 443 in virtual tag even though i have no other service is running on this port , instead its working very well with any other free port like 55000

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
# Server Certificate:
SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/bin/mycert.crt"
# Server Private Key 
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/bin/mykey1.key"
SSLEngine On
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>
```

error :

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:36:52 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:36:52 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:36:52 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:36:52 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:36:52 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
3:36:52 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: How do you know that you don't have any other service running on that port?  Even services that you might not expect to use port 443 may try to do so.   For example, Skype does.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: It appears that you have asked the same question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/609123/apache-is-not-allowing-me-to-use-port-number-443-to-configure-https and the comments there are very helpful.